# Error creating Word object in classic ASP on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, ms-word

In the middle of converting our Intranet from a Windows 2000/IIS 4 box to a Windows 2008/IIS 7 box.  Just doing a straight conversion for now, with an eye on redeveloping some apps in C#.NET in the future.

New server has Word 2010 installed, old has Word 2003.

Running into an issue with a classic ASP app.  Attempting to create and modify a Word document based on a template document.

Receiving following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 

Object required: 'Documents.Open(...)'
```

The code it is attempting to run is as follows:

```
Dim wrdObj
Set wrdObj = Server.CreateObject("Word.application")
Dim wrdDoc
Set wrdDoc = Server.CreateObject("Word.Document")
Set wrdDoc = wrdObj.Documents.Open(docRoot & docName)
' Do word assignments
With wrdDoc
    .Variables("Today").Value = rs.Fields.Item("TODAY").Value & " "
    .Variables("Requester").Value = Request.QueryString("strUser") & " "
    .Variables("Ship_Comp").Value = rs.Fields.Item("TXT_VENDOR_NAME").Value & " "
    .Variables("Ship_Addr").Value = rs.Fields.Item("ADDR").Value & " "
    .Variables("Ship_City").Value = rs.Fields.Item("CITY").Value & " " & rs.Fields.Item("STATE_ZIP").Value
    .Variables("Ship_Country").Value = rs.Fields.Item("COUNTRY").Value & " "
    .Fields.Update
    .Save
End With
'wrdDoc.Section
wrdDoc.Close
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
wrdObj.Quit
Set wrdObj = Nothing
```

It is failing on the following line:

```
Set wrdDoc = wrdObj.Documents.Open(docRoot & docName)
```

I've done a bunch of searches out there, but not many people appear to be using Word 2010 automation in classic ASP for some strange reason...  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into something similar on the 64-bit version of Windows Server 2008 and attempting some Excel automation. Apparently the 64-bit version has some Office automation issues. I'm not sure if they extend to all of Office Automation, or if it's just Excel, but here is the link that I used to fix my problem.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/innovateonoffice/thread/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91?prof=required

I created the folders mentioned in the 2nd post, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I read it, and couldn't believe it.  I tried it - it worked.  Talk about something that would be difficult to just stumble upon!  Thanks a bunch for your help, hyperflow - that worked like a charm.

Comment: Had similar issue and the creation of the "Desktop' folder did resolve my issue. In my case, even though it was a 64 bit O/s (Win 7) I had to create the folder under c:\windows\system32 - nasty nasty nasty.... but it works.